# Eclipse Subclipse icon with red plus sign

Tags: eclipse, svn, icons, subclipse

What does the icon [image] (a red plus sign) in Subclipse mean? What do I do if I want to get whatever is from the repository regarding this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a merge conflict [icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3917925/6309), more specifically a [tree conflict](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html), where a file has been created twice. This [blog post also explains how to resolve them](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/resolving-tree-conflicts).

> A tree conflict occurs when a developer moved/renamed/deleted a file or folder, which another developer either also has moved/renamed/deleted or just modified.

Comment: If it is an evil twins, the simplest resolution is [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2207119/6309).