# How to resolve SVN tree conflict from duplicated file add?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

The same file (an image) was added to both the trunk and my current branch independently and checked in on both. Now there's a tree conflict when I attempt to merge from trunk into my branch. What's the easiest way to resolve this conflict? (just using the standard "resolve" doesn't do anything)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/767763/395718

Comment: I tried removing the file from one, then merging back, but the conflict still came up on that merge. I even tried reverting the branch image folder to back before the file was added, then merge, but the conflict still showed up.